# How to plot pcolor mesh plot with triangles using python

Tags: python

I hope you are doing well.
I want to plot the pcolor mesh plot using python with a triangle as shown below:

I am able to plot with squares but I have a problem with triangles. Can someone help me to do it?

Comment: do you just want to change the markers? Does this help? https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/markers_api.html Can you share what you have already done?

Answer (score 0):

An Unstructured triangular grid contains n_points points and n_tri triangles which can either be specified by the user or automatically generated using a Delaunay triangulation. Here is the syntax:

[image]
matplotlib.tri.Triangulation(x, y, triangles=None, mask=None

here is an image that can help and this site (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/create-a-pseudocolor-plot-of-an-unstructured-triangular-grid-in-python-using-matplotlib/) seems good if you some more information.